# Securesocial with Twitter and Playframework 2.0 on Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0, securesocial

I have sucesfully installed securesocial in my play 2 app and I have it working for google and facebook. But i am having an issue with twitter

My conf file has the following

```
#
# Twitter
#
securesocial.twitter.requestTokenURL=https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token
securesocial.twitter.accessTokenURL=https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token
securesocial.twitter.authorizationURL=https://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate
securesocial.twitter.consumerKey=mykey
securesocial.twitter.consumerSecret=mysecret
```

but I am getting the following exception.

```
securesocial.provider.AuthenticationException: Authorization failed (server replied with a 401). This can happen if the consumer key was not correct or the signatures did not match.
```

My key and secret are the same as they are on my twitter API account app that I have created for this app. I have also included the website and the @anywhere domain from where this request is being called from.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe an issue with the @anywhere feature of Twitter. Try to register a Twitter app with localhost.

Comment: I have the app deployed on heroku, so using the heroku url

Comment: No clue :( Maybe try using the sample (https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/tree/master/samples) and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the time in your computer is properly set.  Twitter will return that error if the local time in your computer is out of some offset compared to the time in their servers. Hope this helps.